# Updating Binding of a listview is causing Object reference not set to an instance of an object

Tags: c#, wpf, wcf, listview

I have WPF window view that contains a listview which has a list binding. Everything works great until i update the target source and then i get an Object reference not set to an instance of an object error message when request selecteditem from list view.

The code below is creating a new instance of a wcf azure web service and this is binded to a listview in wpf. It works great, all the rows contain the correct information.

The problem is when i want to update the source for new items.

```
ServiceReference1.Service1Client server = new ServiceReference1.Service1Client();

    public List<ServiceReference1.patient> PatientCollection
    {
        get
        {
                return server.getPatients().ToList();       
        }
    }
```

I update the source in a timed event using a timer dispatcher that works fine.

```
  PatientListView.GetBindingExpression(ListView.ItemsSourceProperty).UpdateTarget();
```

But when i want to get selected item after the update i get the exception.

```
private void PatientListView_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {

        //TabControl1.SelectedIndex = 1;

        var item = (ServiceReference1.patient)PatientListView.SelectedItem;
        if (item.ews >= 5)
        {
            var theme = ThemeManager.DetectAppStyle(Application.Current);
            var accent = ThemeManager.GetAccent("Red");
            ThemeManager.ChangeAppStyle(Application.Current.Resources, accent, theme.Item1);
            ....not related code omitted...
        }
```

The error appears right on **var item = (ServiceReference1.patient)PatientListView.SelectedItem;**

Any solutions to updating what's in the selection changed method as well would be much appreciated.

Comment: Are you sure that this is the line the exception is thrown on, it looks like to me that when you are updating the target source, the selected item is changed to null, hence *item.ews* would throw NRE?

Comment: you're right its the next line at if (item.ews >= 5) that is throwing the exception. but i don't understand why it would be null if i update the target source and and the selected item is set every time the selection changes.

Comment: This is expected, changing the ItemsSource means changing the Items, how could you have the same selection when the items have changed. For instance if you have row 16 selected, then update the source, but only 15 items are provided this time, so if the selection was preserved, something like IndexOutOfRangeException would be thrown because there is no 16th element

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should note that the `SelectedItem` of the `ListView` can be `null` (aka. nothing selected). So you need to handle that case.

This can occur when you change/replace the bound collection of the ListView.

```
var item = (ServiceReference1.patient)PatientListView.SelectedItem;
if (item != null && item.ews >= 5)
{
   // your code
}
```

Also you can check the `SelectionChangedEventArgs` that get passed to your method to check what was selected (`RemovedItems`) and what is selected (`AddedItems`)

Comment: That fixed the issue. It never occurred to me that was the issue.